# Get 'subscriptions driven', Youtube API not returning all data available in UI

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

When you look at statistics under youtube videos it will usually look like this

[image: UI tabs]

I am interested in the third tab. I have spent all day reading the youtube documentation but I cannot seem to find a way to GET it. My queries look like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=VIDEOID&key=MYKEY
```

And the statistics part returns the following parameters

```
"statistics": {
"viewCount": "559064",
"likeCount": "5319",
"dislikeCount": "150",
"favoriteCount": "0",
"commentCount": "628"
}
```

Is there any good way to get this number, subscriptions driven?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need to use [YouTube Analytics API.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/)

There is a [subscribersGained](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#subscribersGained) metric which

> In reports that use either the video dimension or the filter parameter
>   to restrict the response to only include data for a particular video,
>   the subscribersGained metric will only include statistics from the
>   specified video's watch page.